# Why do we have HTTP verbs like GET, POST and PUT instead of SELECT, INSERT and Update

Tags: http

In web world using the `HTTP` protocol why do we have verbs like `GET`, `POST` and `PUT` instead of traditionally used words in computer science vocabulary like `SELECT`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. We also have `DELETE` `HTTP` verb that makes perfect sense unlike others.

Comment: HTTP at this point is almost as "traditional" as SQL.  Who's to say which one should be changed to suit the other?  If we're going to change them, why not replace both with the CRUD verbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite certain why you believe SQL terms are "traditionally used words in computer science vocabulary." They're not even ubiquitous in database programming. When I worked in dBASE, it used `LIST` for a similar concept to SQL's `SELECT`. Why do you believe SQL had a special place in history when HTTP was being developed?

The first version of HTTP only had one verb: GET. It did the most obvious thing: get a page. HTTP wasn't built around CRUD. It was built around fetching hyperlinked pages. Later HEAD (for efficiency) and POST (for interaction) came along. It still had nothing to do with databases.

After years of use, concepts like REST have been built on top of HTTP, but it's a long way from what HTTP was designed for.

SELECT would be a very bad verb to replace GET. GET fetches a document based on its address. It's not a general query verb.

Comment: OP never explicitly mentioned SQL terms. This doesn't explain _why_ the verbs were chosen over others, though.

Comment: @jhpratt Was SELECT used by anything other than SQL in 1994? I don't remember seeing it anywhere except SQL in the 80s. I don't believe the "why" here is answerable. Why not "FETCH" rather than "GET?" Why not "get" or "Get?" The original protocol was very simple, meant to solve a specific purpose, and not derived from any deep first principles: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html

Comment: `I don't believe the "why" here is answerable.` That's why I voted to close as POB, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

> The term hypertext was coined by Ted Nelson in 1965 in the Xanadu Project, which was in turn inspired by Vannevar Bush's 1930s vision of the microfilm-based information retrieval and management "memex" system described in his 1945 essay "As We May Think". Tim Berners-Lee and his team at CERN are credited with inventing the original HTTP, along with HTML and the associated technology for a web server and a text-based web browser.

Http (aka Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)) was created by Ted Berners-Lee and his team.

> SQL was initially developed at IBM by Donald D. Chamberlin and Raymond F. Boyce after learning about the relational model from Ted Codd[15] in the early 1970s.

SQL was developed by people at IBM

---

Different people developed them, and thus they named similar actions, differently.

Comment: OP never explicitly mentioned SQL terms. This doesn't explain _why_ the verbs were chosen over others, though.

Comment: Yes it does. "Different people developed them, and thus they named similar actions, differently."
The people who developed them, named them, respectively. 
While I agree with you that this isn't a very good question and should possibly be closed, OP's question was answered. HTTP terms are called the way they are because the people who developed them decided to call it that.

Comment: If you believe a question should be closed, you should flag it and _not_ answer it.